# Powershell claims object is null but I can see values

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare two objects and I can see both objects have values (and they are the same), but running the compare results in error referenceobject is null. See screenshot
Not sure where to go with this.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please provide your actual test code and output here in the [edit] to your question.  Screenshots of code aren't very helpful.  A [mcve] is preferred.

Comment: We don't do screenshots here. Please copy/paste the text of the script and output into the question. You'll be much more likely to get a good answer this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a quick check to see if any value is equal to null and then do a comparison if values are found. Even if you can see both objects have values, your ps command may not.

The following accepts null values:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject @($Value1 | Select-Object) -DifferenceObject @($Value2 | Select-Object)
```